# Calculus Lab Problem Differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am kind of confused on how to differentiate this function.

Here is the problem:

$$P(t) = \frac{1}{(1 + e^{-t})} $$

Use the differentiation rules to compute the exact value of $P'(2)$.

Certain steps to get me in the right direction would be awesome too!

Comment: Have you actually applied the differentiation rules? It seems pretty strightforward

Comment: No I'm not quite sure where to start. I haven't taken calculus for a year.

Comment: Do you know how to differentiate a fraction? And how to differentiate an exponential?

Comment: I'm trying right now, but what do I do with the -t?

Comment: Apply the rule to differentiate the exponential of a function: d( exp(f(t)) ) / dx = f'(t) exp(f(t))

Comment: Okay so basically:

1. Bring the denominator up into the numerator.
2. Apply chain rule.
3. Move (1+e^(-t))^2 to the denominator.
4. Then input 2 into the derivative of P(t).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Use the following rules

1. $\frac{d(1/f(x))}{dx} = -\frac{1}{f(x)^2}\frac{df(x)}{dx}$
2. $\frac{d(e(x))}{dx} = e(x)$
3. $\frac{d(f(x)+g(x))}{dx} = \frac{df(x)}{dx}+\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$
4. $\frac{d(1)}{dx} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to solve this. differentiating $$p^{-1} = 1 + e^{-t}$$ gives you $$-p^{-2}p' = -e^{-t}.$$  subbing $t = 2$ gives you $$ p'(2) = \left(\frac{p(2)}{e}\right)^2 =\left(\frac1{e(1+e^{-2})}\right)^2=\frac{e^2}{(1+e^2)^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$P\left( t \right) =\frac { 1 }{ 1+{ e }^{ -t } } \\ { P }^{ \prime  }\left( t \right) ={ \left( \left( 1+{ e }^{ -t } \right) ^{ -1 } \right)  }^{ \prime  }=-\left( \left( 1+{ e }^{ -t } \right) ^{ -2 } \right) \left( -{ e }^{ -t } \right) =\frac { { e }^{ -t } }{ { \left( 1+{ e }^{ -t } \right)  }^{ 2 } } \\ { P }^{ \prime  }\left( 2 \right) =\frac { { e }^{ -2 } }{ { \left( 1+{ e }^{ -2 } \right)  }^{ 2 } } =\frac { { e }^{ 2 } }{ \left( { e }^{ 2 }+1 \right) ^{ 2 } } $$